# What is best choice (wcf, web-service, win service) for my task

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services, windows-services

Now, I have one ASP.NET MVC application. I have the several methods in ASP.NET MVC application which retrieve data from external windows desktop(not mine) application (by tcp/ip). And now I want to move this methods to external service(program), also other methods( send email messages and other proccesses which now runing in separate thread). This is my first experience with web services/wcf. And, what is the better way to do that: wcf, web service, win service?
Thanks

**MORE DETAILS:**
In ASP.NET MVC app I get various information from external desktop (not mine) application(by TCP/IP). For example in this program creates events: movies, sports, theaters, and schedule for them. Also, how many seats left for a particular session and many other.
Different types of informations can be obtained in various ways. Sometimes, I check every minute that there are updates( list of events, shedules). Sometimes I need every minute to get other information for cahcing(how many seats left for session). Therefore, I have many tasks are performed in a separate thread and approach described bellow.

For updates from external win program I using the following approach:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AddTask("UpdateFromExternalProgram", "60", 60);
}

private static CacheItemRemovedCallback _onCacheRemove = null;
public static void AddTask(string name, string value,int seconds)
{
    _onCacheRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemoved);
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, value, null,
                       DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                       CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, _onCacheRemove);
}

    private static  void CacheItemRemoved(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
   {
        if (reason == CacheItemRemovedReason.Expired)
        {               
               AddTask(key, value.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(value));
               GetUpdatesFromExternalProgram();               
        }
   }
private static void GetUpdatesFromPremiera()
{
    //creates TCP/IP client, send request, and parse response
}
```

Also, in a separate thread sends all emails on site( registration, feedback, other information):

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(SendEmailInSeparateThread), senderInfo);
```

And, I want to move this functional into other app: wcf, web service or win service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [avoid implementing recurring background tasks](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) in ASP.NET applications. A Windows Service is a better candidate to implement this functionality.

Comment: Why windows service not web service? What is prons and cons?

Comment: It will depend on the web service type. But if you host this web service in IIS (classic ASMX or IIS hosted WCF service) you are using an ASP.NET application. In this case read the Phil Haack article why is it bad to implement recurring background tasks in ASP.NET applications. At any time IIS could recycle this ASP.NET application stopping all activity and killing all threads.